# How to run same Keras model on different GPUs in parallel independently with different data?

Tags: python, tensorflow, parallel-processing, keras

Let's say I have two instances of a keras model `model0` and `model1` and datasets `data0` and `data1`. If I have two or more GPUs, is there a way that I can train `model0` on `data0` on `GPU0` and `model1` on `data1` on `GPU1` in parallel? All of the methods I have found so far split the training of a single model over multiple gpus.

Thanks!

Comment: Just to be curious, have you tried at terminal: ‘python model0.py > result0.txt &’ and ‘python model1.py > result1.txt &’? Does it give error?

Comment: I haven't, but this would not work for my setup as this is part of a much larger process that is going on. It just doesn't make sense to do it from the command line.

Answer (score 1):

How about multiprocessing?

You just execute you function in a multiprocessing pool twice:

What you need to consider:

- Your model have to be defined or loaded inside the function
- You need a parameter which mask the GPUs. Masking is possible by setting the env variable CUDA_VISIBLE_DEVICES(you also have to do this inside the function)
- You could pass the different training data via a parameter
- it would be best to save the resulting models into different files and then load it from your main program

So basically passing keras/tensorflow sessions between your main programm and the functions in the multiprocessing tool is a nogo. But if you keep everything keras/tensorflow related inside the function and mask the GPUs differently then you're good to go.